# LibreOffice Command Line Conversion - No Output File?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, pdf, conversion

I am using LibreOffice installed on my Linux box and I seem to be having a weird problem in that the conversion seems to be taking place, and there seem to be no errors, but there is no output file in the specified output directory.

Here is an example of the command I am using:

```
/opt/libreoffice3.6/program/soffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf /dir/file.pptx --outdir /dir
```

And here is the result of that command:

```
convert /dir/file.pptx -> /dir/file.pdf using impress_pdf_Export
```

But the problem is that after running the conversion `/dir/file.pdf` does not exist.

I tried a doc file and the command worked, and saved properly. Even though the conversion seems to be taking place with the pptx file, it does not seem to save it anywhere, oddly.

Do any of you have any suggestions?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 - the same problem happened to me. Turned out, the conversion from command line doesn't work at all if there is already GUI version of LibreOffice running.

Answer (score 3):

I use this command and it work properly:

```
libreoffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf --outdir ~/dir  ~/dir/file_to_convert.pptx
```

But if you can convert a .doc file, you should be able to do the same with .pptx file. It's odd...

Answer (score 2):

As noted in [a comment to OP](https://askubuntu.com/users/363813/dummy00001), it is vital that no instance of LibreOffice is running.

When I was attempting to do a `soffice` conversion, I hadn't run LibO at all, so I thought this wasn't my problem. However, on checking Task Manager, it showed "soffice quick-start" running, and this was preventing the conversion.

So it seems this [old bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37531) is still present in latest LibO (I'm running v. 5.1.1.2 under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS), and it's worth being aware of it given the silent "quick-start" instance of `soffice`.

Comment: It appears that the [bug was fixed in 2016](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37531).